# Centralize Login System

Tags: php, authentication

At work, there are a few different websites and they all access to the websites on the network (Intranet), for example:

```
http://192.168.1.50 (Sales Panel)
http://192.168.1.52 (Other Panel)
http://192.168.1.53 (And different project)
```

I have to create a new account on each website and it become a bit of pain to use.

Then I thought why not create a Centralize Login System so each website can create and check the login account from a Centralize Login System.

For example, `UserA` have ability to login to `http://192.168.1.50` or `http://192.168.1.53` but not on `http://192.168.1.52` (cookies is not needed, $_SESSION is fine).

How that should be implemented in regarding sending the request and response from a Centralize Login System?

Should I use `HTTP GET` for the request and response back a JSON object with several properties? For example

```
connect_status - "SUCCESS" - check was successful, "FAIL" - check was unsuccessful)
connect_id - UserId
connect_username - the username
```

If user successful logged in and user refresh the page - should it recheck the login or session via Centralize Login System?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How that should be implemented in regarding sending the request and response from a Centralize Login System?

That's entirely up to you. Just keep in mind that there are already many systems which were designed for very similar scenarios. Your use case is very similar to things that could be provided via [kerberos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/kadm5.examples-connect.php), [radius](http://php.net/manual/en/book.radius.php), or even [ldap](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php) (if you have an existing AD) servers. If you have any of those around you already, it may be easier to query them rather than writing your own solution.

If you want your own, JSON response is as good as any other. Just make sure you verify the response is valid.

> Should I use HTTP GET for the request and response back a JSON object with several properties?

Sounds pretty typical.

> If user successful logged in and user refresh the page - should it recheck the login or session via Centralize Login System?

That depends on your backend technology and how quickly do you want to invalidate tickets. Are you ok with someone having access without authentication a couple of hours after changing the password, or disabling the account? Can you push a request to invalidate the authentication token / session files from the Auth controller to the app servers? How many requests per second do you get from all applications in total and can you handle all of the resulting auth requests in one place?

Answer some of those questions and you should get an idea of how you need to handle the rechecking / token caching / invalidation.

Also, in case you can/want to push some of the authentication handling to the client, have a look at protocols like [oauth](http://oauth.net/).